# How to shorten import statements while developing a Python package?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I am designing a Python package. Please see below the project structure-

```
android_py
├── README.md
├── setup.py
└── android_py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── options.py
    └── android.py
```

Below is the content of `setup.py`-

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='android_py',
      version='0.1',
      description='The description goes here',
      url='http://github.com/example_user/android_py',
      author='Bob',
      author_email='abc@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=find_packages(),
      zip_safe=False,
      )
```

The above package can be installed successfully by using `python setup.py`. However, in order to use this package, I need to write long `import` statements as shown below-

```
from android_py.android import Android
from android_py.options import Power

my_robot = Android()
my_robot.set_power(Power.On)
```

As you can see, there are following two issues-

1. The first import, i.e., `from android_py.android import Android` is way too long and not user-friendly as it is difficult to remember. I think something shorter such as `import android` is much nicer.
2. The second import, i.e., `from android_py.options import Power` is troublesome. It should be imported automatically by the first import.

Can you please suggest me how to reconfigure this package in order to overcome with above-mentioned issues? Please note that I am using Python 2.7 (if that matters)!

Comment: Import `Robot` and `Power` in your android's `__init__`. From outside you can import your API by `from android import Robot, Power`.

Comment: @return42: I agree with your suggestion! Thank you. I updated the question and made it much clear.

Comment: This is the way I do export my package API. BTW you are free to change your package without any impact to the external API.

Comment: @return42: thanks again. how about the second issue?

Comment: Without going any deeper: add `Power` as an property to your `Android` class definition. Then you can call `my_robot.set_power(my_robot.Power.on)` .. hope it was clear what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Additional to my comments I will try to give a short example. Say you have a power.py:

```
class Power:
   On = True
```

and in the same package a android.py:

```
from . import power

class Android:
    Power = power.Power
```

In the android_py package `__init__.py`:

```
from .android import Android
```

Now, from outside in your app.py, main.py or whatever you can:

```
from android_py import Android
my_robot = Android()
my_robot.set_power(my_robot.Power.On)
```

BTW: I'am not very happy with the package name android_py. Name it also `android`, it is no problem to have an `android.py` in a package `android`. Or explainted in path names: it is no problem to have `android/android.py`. With the relative import `.` used in the `android.py` and `__init__.py` in the example above it should work.

Comment: If you are looking for a project boilerplate and you are familiar with Makefiles, may you like to take a look at my [fspath](https://github.com/return42/fspath) project. It is a small project with a sophisticated boilerplate. I'am not talking about fspath itself, more about the boilerplate and how I organize code and documentation.

Comment: To be complete; the boilerplate (template) itself is maintained [here](https://github.com/return42/boilerplate). The [documentation](https://return42.github.io/boilerplate) needs some more work / sorry :)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for? https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/everything.html

Edit: Using the code in the link, I was able to do this:

```
import funniest.funniest
import types

print(dir(funniest))

print([getattr(funniest, a) for a in dir(funniest)
    if isinstance(getattr(funniest, a), types.FunctionType)])

print(funniest.funniest.joke())

print("works")
```

This calls joke() in ./python-packaging-master/funniest/funniest/**init**.py

Just change the folder structure in the example and you can plainly call `import funniest`

I'm sure you can apply the same thing to your package.

Comment: a bit confused. package structure wise `from funniest.command_line import main` is almost similar to `from android_py.android import Android`. Am I missing something obvious? What I understood is that I can put `import Android`  in `__init__.py` and then I can use `from android_py import Android`